# How can I call a db2 function and have it return multiple xml record data?

Tags: sql, xml, db2

In SQL, I need to create xml code that looks like this:

```
    <Phone>
       <PhoneTypeCode tc="12">Mobile</PhoneTypeCode>
       <Area>801</Area>
       <DialNumber>9996666</DialNumber>
    </Phone>
    <Phone>
       <PhoneTypeCode tc="2">Business</PhoneTypeCode>
       <Area>801</Area>
       <DialNumber>1113333</DialNumber>
    </Phone>
```

When I run this sql, I correctly get two rows of data, as I would expect:

```
select
  xmlelement( 
     Name "Phone", 
     xmlelement( 
       name "PhoneTypeCode", 
       xmlattributes( 
         trim(p1.phtype) as "tc" 
       ), 
       trim(p1.desc) 
     ), 
     xmlelement(name "AreaCode", p1.area), 
     xmlelement(name "DialNumber", p1.phone)                   
  ) as xml 
from phone as p1 where p1.entityid = 256285;
```

These are the two rows of data I get back, exactly as I expected:

```
    <Phone><PhoneTypeCode tc="12">Mobile</PhoneTypeCode><AreaCode>351</AreaCode>       <DialNumber>4443333</DialNumber></Phone> 

    <Phone><PhoneTypeCode tc="2">Business</PhoneTypeCode><AreaCode>351</AreaCode><DialNumber>3911111</DialNumber></Phone>
```

However, when I try putting this same code in a function and call this function, I get this error:

SQL State: 21000 
Vendor Code: -811 
Message: [SQL0811] Result of SELECT more than one row. Cause . . . . . :   The result table of a SELECT INTO statement, a subquery, or a subselect of a SET statement contains more than one row.  The error type is 2. If the error type is 1 then a SELECT INTO statement attempted to return more than one row.  If the error type is 2 then a subselect of a basic predicate has produced more than one row.  Only one row is allowed. Recovery  . . . :   Change the selection so that only one result row is returned and then try the request again.  The DECLARE CURSOR, OPEN, and FETCH statements must be used to process more than one result row.  For a subquery the IN, EXISTS, ANY or ALL predicates can be used to process more than one result row.  If one row was expected, there may be data errors, such as duplicate rows, that are causing more than one row to be returned.

**How can I fix this function so that it will return all rows of data as one block of xml code as I expect?

```
    CREATE or replace FUNCTION xml_entity_phones ( 
    #Entity_ID bigint) 
    RETURNS xml 

    LANGUAGE SQL 
    NOT DETERMINISTIC 
    reads SQL DATA 
    RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT 
    NO EXTERNAL ACTION 
    ALLOW PARALLEL 
    NOT FENCED 

    begin 
    return ( 
    select 
        xmlelement( 
          Name "Phone", 
          xmlelement( 
            name "PhoneTypeCode", 
            xmlattributes( 
              trim(p.phtype) as "tc" 
            ), 
            trim(p.desc) 
          ), 
          xmlelement(name "AreaCode", p.area), 
          xmlelement(name "DialNumber", p.phone)                   
        ) as xml 
    from phone p where p.entityid = #entity_id 
    ); 
    end 
    ;
```

The procedure that calls this function, is building an xml file that includes different types of phones, which I wanted to build with the above function.

The end goal is to have an xml document (valid or not) that looks like this:

```
    <TXLife>
       <TXLifeRequest>
          <OLife>
             <Person>
                <Phone>
                   <PhoneTypeCode tc="12">Mobile...
                   <Area...
                   <DialNumber...
                </Phone>
                <Phone>
                   <PhoneTypeCode tc="2">Business...
                   <Area...
                   <DialNumber...
                </Phone> 
                ...
```

I was hoping to build the entire phone section xml with a function call like: xml_entity_phones(bigint(e.entityid)).

---

OK, I changed the function to look like this with xmlagg():

```
begin               
    return (
        select
            xmlagg(
                xmlelement(
                    Name "Phone", 
                    xmlelement(
                        name "PhoneTypeCode", 
                        xmlattributes(
                        trim(p.phtype) as "tc"
                        ), 
                    trim(p.desc)
                    ),
                xmlelement(name "AreaCode", p.area),
                xmlelement(name "DialNumber", p.phone)                   
                )
            ) as xml
        from phone p 
        where p.entityid = #entity_id   
    );
end
```

But now when I call the function with values(xml_entity_phones(256285));, I get ++++++++++++++ as a result.  And when I call the procedure that calls this function, I get this error:

SQL State: 22023
Vendor Code: -802
Message: [SQL0802] Data conversion or data mapping error. Cause . . . . . :   Error type 10 has occurred  10 -- User-defined function returned a mapping error.

I did notice that when I include an extra element of Phones using xmlagg as suggested in a couple of answers below, that it does return the xmlagg() result successfully.  However I can't have that extra element of Phones because it goes against the standard I need to adhere to.

Is there a way to return the xmlagg without the extra layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where you would use XMLAGG():

```
begin 
return ( 
select 
    xmlelement(name "Phones", xmlagg(
    xmlelement( 
      Name "Phone", 
      xmlelement( 
        name "PhoneTypeCode", 
        xmlattributes( 
          trim(p.phtype) as "tc" 
        ), 
        trim(p.desc) 
      ), 
      xmlelement(name "AreaCode", p.area), 
      xmlelement(name "DialNumber", p.phone)                   
    )
   )) as xml 
from phone p where p.entityid = #entity_id 
); 
end
```

Obviously, I don't have your data but this simple example shows that the approach works:

```
$ db2 "create or replace function t () returns xml language sql begin \
return (select xmlagg(xmlelement(name \"tab\", tabname )) from syscat.tables \
where tabname like '%AUTH%' and tabschema = 'SYSCAT'); end"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
$ db2 "values t()"

1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
<tab>COLAUTH</tab><tab>DBAUTH</tab><tab>INDEXAUTH</tab><tab>LIBRARYAUTH</tab>
<tab>MODULEAUTH</tab><tab>PACKAGEAUTH</tab><tab>PASSTHRUAUTH</tab><tab>ROLEAUTH
</tab><tab>ROUTINEAUTH</tab><tab>SCHEMAAUTH</tab><tab>SEQUENCEAUTH</tab>tab>
SURROGATEAUTHIDS    </tab><tab>TABAUTH</tab><tab>TBSPACEAUTH</tab><tab>
VARIABLEAUTH</tab><tab>WORKLOADAUTH</tab><tab>XSROBJECTAUTH</tab>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

  1 record(s) selected.
```

Comment: This is what I was hoping for, but the standard set by the calling procedure (which is really building a large xml doc that includes phones, which I was hoping to build with this function) does not allow me to use a parent such as "Phones".  It has to be in this type of format:

Comment: You can simply omit the outer XMLELEMENT() to get an XML fragment containing a sequence of Phone elements, though this won't be a valid XML document.

Comment: I will edit my original question with the required format, but is there any way to concatenate the multiple rows into one xml statement inside the function?

Comment: As shown in my edit of the original post, I added xmlagg() and get a bunch of +++++++  as a result when I call with values(xml_entity_phones(256285)) ;

Comment: There must be something different in your data and/or environment, as the example works perfectly fine for me, as can be seen above.

Answer (score 0):

When you issue a SQL select, you are retrieving a resultset (in some way a cursor). What you have is not a XML, it is a resultset that has two XML documents, or two rows. A XML document has just one parent, here you have two parents (phone)

You can retrieve a cursor like the one you have via a Stored Procedure.

```
create procedure x ()
P1:BEGIN
DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CLIENT FOR
  xmlelement( 
     Name "Phone", 
     ...
     xmlelement(name "DialNumber", p1.phone)                   
  ) as xml 
  from phone as p1 where p1.entityid = 256285;
open cursor1;
END P1;
```

Comment: A function cannot retrieve a ResultSet. However, you can create a Table function that retrieves a kind of table, but with just a stored procedure you can do what you want.

Comment: Or merge the two XML documents into onem with a common parent, such as "phones"